# How to reverse the Salesforce Console toolkit action of 'blinkCustomConsoleComponentButtonText'

Tags: service-cloud-console

Trying to figure out how to stop a button blinking, having applied the sforce.console.blinkCustomConsoleComponentButtonText method to it.

Any suggestions ? I have tried applying a zero second blink interval which errors out - requires something greater than zero.  Nothing in the docs that stood out to me.

Any assistance most appreciated.

Regards
CH

Comment: did you get answer for this? I am also looking forward for its solution. Thanks

Comment: No never sorted it sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's another (although undocumented) solution to this:
`sforce.console.removeBlinkCustomConsoleComponentButtonText()` (no arguments required)

This actually disables the blinking of the button text (whereas using `blinkCustomConsoleComponentButtonText` with the same text as the original button, still causes the button element to change periodically - just with the same caption over and over).

Answer (score 1):

We can stop blinking if we give same text as the button text in alternate text parameter in blinkCustomConsoleComponentButtonText method

eg: Suppose if the Button text is 'Contact Alerts'. 
    if we call **sforce.console.blinkCustomConsoleComponentButtonText('HI', 10,              callbackfunction)**.

It will start blinking.

Now if we give same aternate text as button text like **sforce.console.blinkCustomConsoleComponentButtonText('Contact Alerts', 10, callbackfunction).**

It will stop blinking.

Thanks

Comment: Well there you go! Be nice if toolkit had something more formal but this will do nicely! Once I test I will tick as answer. Cheers!